Haskell function with data pattern match and second argument gives Equations have different numbers of arguments
In Haskell I have the following data structure
data Circ = IN String
    | NOT Circ
    | AND Circ Circ
    | OR Circ Circ
    | XOR Circ Circ

I can pattern match functions on this like so:
size :: Circ -> Int
size (IN _) = 0
..
size (XOR a b) = 1 + (size a) + (size b)

but when I try this with an additional argument:
simulate :: Circ -> [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
simulate (IN a) c = findIn c a
simulate (NOT a) c = not $ simulate a c
simulate (AND a b) c = all (simulate a c) (simulate b c)
simulate (OR a b) c = any (simulate a c) (simulate b c)
simulate (XOR a b) = xor (simulate a c) (simulate b c)

I get the error Equations for ‘simulate’ have different numbers of arguments.
How can I write a function that pattern matches a data structure with extra arguments?
I tried rewriting the brackets and couldn't find anything about this online.
I expect it to put the values of the data structure in some of the arguments and receive the next argument alongside it.
Thanks in advance!

your last clause has no c in the head

simulate (XOR a b) c = xor (simulate a c) (simulate b c)

This is caused by the missing c in the last clause:
simulate :: Circ -> [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
simulate (IN a) c = findIn c a
simulate (NOT a) c = not $ simulate a c
simulate (AND a b) c = all (simulate a c) (simulate b c)
simulate (OR a b) c = any (simulate a c) (simulate b c)
simulate (XOR a b) c = xor (simulate a c) (simulate b c)
Another problem is that all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool function [Hackage], and any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool function [Hackage] work with a Foldable of items, not two parameters; so:
simulate :: Circ -> [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
simulate (IN a) c = findIn c a
simulate (NOT a) c = not $ simulate a c
simulate (AND a b) c = simulate a c && simulate b c
simulate (OR a b) c = simulate a c || simulate b c
simulate (XOR a b) c = simulate a c `xor` simulate b c
But we can probably simplify this by making abstraction of the operator:
data Op1 = Not

data Op2 = And | Or | Xor

data Circ
  = IN String
  | Op1 Op1 Circ
  | Op2 Op2 Circ Circ
and work with:
func1 :: Op1 -> Bool -> Bool
func1 Not = not

func2 :: Op2 -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool
func2 And = (&&)
func2 Or = (||)
func2 Xor = xor

simulate :: Circ -> [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
simulate (IN a) c = findIn c a
simulate (Op1 f a) c = func1 f (simulate a c)
simulate (Op2 f a b) c = func2 f (simulate a c) (simulate b c)

Thanks, I can't believe I missed that!
